# How to print a div of another page using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

How can we print a div which is in another page[other page] ? If so how can we achieve this?

Code what i have tried so far?

```
function editBilling(invoiceId,invoiceName)
    {
        window.location=url+"admin/editBilling/"+invoiceId+"/"+invoiceName;


            printMode();

        //$("#disBillingDet").printElement({printMode:'popup'});
    }
    function printMode()
    {
        alert("print");
        $("#disBillingDet").printElement({printMode:'popup'});
    }
```

The page reloads before going to the page... how to achieve this

Comment: try `load` functionality ` $("#disBillingDet").load(url+"admin/editBilling/"+invoiceId+"/"+invoiceName)`

Comment: now it not going to that page???

Comment: you won't go to that page you load that page's content to your current page with `div id="#disBillingDet"`

Comment: but this div id is the other page ? should i assign a div in the current page

Comment: simplified: u have a div with id `disBillingDet` in page1 and you want to load page1's div(id `disBillingDet`) with page2 div with id `container`, correct me with your requirements.so that time you can use `$('#disBillingDet').load('your html url #container');` in your page1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jQuery load() function, like

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

This will load div with "Container" ID into "result" div